# How to convert a temporary table to permanent table in a single atomic operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-5.7

How to convert a temporary table to a static table in a single atomic operation, while still being agnostic to the table structure but yet preserving it, in MySQL?

For a pre-created temporary table of:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp SELECT 0 AS Col1, 'text' AS Col2;
ALTER TABLE _tmp ADD UNIQUE INDEX (Col1, Col2);
```

Of course, one could always go:

```
CREATE TABLE permanent SELECT * FROM _tmp; -- 1
ALTER TABLE permanent ADD UNIQUE INDEX (Col1, Col2); -- 2
```

or, which I, for lack of a better solution, am using:

```
-- mostly agnostic to the structure unless for generated or auto-increment columns
CREATE TABLE permanent LIKE _tmp; -- 1
INSERT INTO permanent SELECT * FROM _tmp; -- 2
```

As shown above, right now I can only manage to do it with at least 2 (DDL + (DDL or DML)) statements.

Is there a way I can improve this to a single DDL? Perhaps a functionality that facilitates a feature combining `LIKE` & `INSERT`?

Comment: DDL statements are not executed as part of any transaction.

Comment: As [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html) claims, CREATE TABLE causes implicit COMMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE permanent
SELECT * FROM _tmp;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1534ece6bf6288b96f9c7c239a9c1eb9)

or (if you need in unique key presence)

```sql
CREATE TABLE permanent ( UNIQUE KEY `Col1` (`Col1`,`Col2`) )
SELECT * FROM _tmp;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72848cc7d86c173a95657916124be17d)

Comment: I think your 2nd solution is interesting. It doesn't satisfy structure agnosticism (which can be solved separately through the use of prepared statements and meta tables), but it does create the table with the same structure indeed in a single atomic operation! Thanks.